# How to get deb package from Java gradle project that register app to systemd

Tags: java, gradle, systemd

How to get a deb package from a Java Gradle project which after installation of the deb file automatically generates **/etc/systemd/system/project.service**, and adds binary files in **/var/project/bin/**, and config files in **/etc/project/**.
Something like https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin but with systemd support.
Sorry for bad English!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that I can use the [nebula-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin) that mention in question.
I just need to add this lines to **build.gradle** file:

```
buildDeb {
  link('/etc/systemd/system/project.service', '/opt/project/bin/project.service')
}
```

And also create a **project.service** file like below and make the plugin moves the service file to install directory of deb package:

```
[Unit]
Description=<description>

[Service]
User=<user>
Group=<group>
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/project
ExecStart=/opt/project/bin/project > /var/log/project/project.log
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The code below will copy service file *(if you put it in the bin directory of the project root)* and all other necessary files to install directory of deb file:

```
ospackage {
  packageName = 'project'

  configurationFile "/opt/project/bin/project.service"

  into '/opt/project'

  from(jar.outputs.files) {
    into 'lib'
  }
  from(configurations.runtime) {
    into 'lib'
  }
  from('build/libs') {
    into 'lib'
  }
  from('conf'){
    into 'conf'
  }
  from('bin') {                      //project.service is in bin directory
    fileType = CONFIG | NOREPLACE    //wont replace any configurationFile in this directory
    into 'bin'
  }
  from('build/scripts') {
    into 'bin'
    exclude 'database'
    fileMode = 0550
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a new problem, now each time I build a new version and install it, I need to run the following command: `systemctl daemon-reload` how to get rid of this command? I know its because of **project.service** changes.

Comment: I figure it out. I edit my answer. by setting **project.service** as **configurationFile** and adding `fileType = CONFIG | NOREPLACE` into **from into** part related to **cozet.service**